# Collision & Work

Tags: homework-and-exercises

Let's assume there is an unusual guy and whenever he is shot, the bullets actually jump off of him towards the opposite direction, in the x-axis. I need to find the work applied by the guy per minute on the bullets.

So he stands still / moves with constant velocity towards the shooter while being shot. Since his velocity is not changing, his momentum is not changing as well and I would conclude that the bullets must move back in the opposite direction with same velocity after colliding with the guy.

That means the kinetic energy of the bullets do not change. 
So in this case, does it mean that the guy is not exerting any work on the bullets in both cases where he stands still and where he is moving with constant velocity?

Answer (score -1):

He would always be exerting force through his feet onto the ground.  The earth is very large so we don't worry about the momentum change of the earth.

Comment: alright, and when I consider just the bullets and the guy, he doesn't exert any force on the bullets in this case?

Comment: Consider it like a shock wave, he exerts a force on the bullet and this force is very quickly transferred to his feet and then into the ground.  Like a sound wave going thru his body.  If he was on ice (slippery) he would actually move backwards.

Comment: I don't see how this answer is related to work or kinetic energy.

Answer (score -1):

The bullets' velocity is changing but no work is being exerted. There's a difference between speed and velocity. Speed is the magnitude of velocity - how fast something is moving - while velocity includes both magnitude (speed) and direction of motion. So if the bullets go back in the opposite direction at the same speed after hitting him, their velocity is now the negative of what it previously was. if the velocity was $v$, the total change in velocity is $-2v$. This means there was a change in momentum, so if the guy's velocity stays the same something else must be changing in momentum so it is conserved (probably the Earth, as the other answer suggested). Anyway, the net change in kinetic energy is zero so there's no work.

Comment: No. When the bullet is being stopped, negative work, eventually equal to -KE, is being done. Then when the bullet is accelerated back from v=0 to its original speed the work is +KE, so the net work done is zero!

Comment: The statements about the momentum are correct.

Comment: @Bill You're right, I edited my answer.

Comment: The question assumes the bullets would bounce off at equal velocity but this would likely not be the case, but yes momentum is still conserved and it is the earth that eventually absorbs it.